# ffmpeg add a watermark programmatically (overlay filter)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, overlay, watermark

I am trying to implement a watermark, a png over a video while the video is playing.

I configure three filters, as i saw in some examples:

1. Input video   (INPUT 1)

   ```
   avfilter_graph_create_filter(&filt_src,avfilter_get_by_name("buffer"),"in", buffersrc_args, NULL,graph);
   ```
2. Png to overlay  (INPUT 2)

   ```
   avfilter_graph_create_filter(&bufferovrlay_ctx,bufferovrlay, "overlay", argsStrOvrlay, NULL,graph);
   ```
3. Output video (Output)

   ```
   avfilter_graph_create_filter(&filt_out, avfilter_get_by_name("ffbuffersink"),"out", NULL, buffersink_params, graph)
   ```

At this point iḿ not sure if i am setting correctly the parameters of the overlay filter, because i did not found any example but the function returns ok.

After creating the filters i call avfilter_graph_parse2(graph, "overlay", inputs, &outputs)
also with no error returned.

Finally i call `avfilter_graph_config(graph, NULL);` and i get the following error:

> -22 (AVERROR_INVALIDDATA)

I found a lot of examples but always using the command line. What do you think i am doing wrong? Someone has an programmatically example?